# nginx redirecting domains with ssl

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have a new domain (my-future-domain.com) that I am trying to use to replace my current domain (my-current-domain.com). I am using a DigitalOcean Nginx server on Ubuntu and believe that I should be taking the following steps in order to replace the current domain with my new domain, but I have never dealt with domain migrations before which is why I would like feedback on the steps I plan to take.

**1)** Point A record to IP associated with current server and CNAME to A record

*A* = my-future-domain.com directs to 100.200.1.90

*CNAME* = www.my-future-domain.com is an alias of my-future-domain.com

**2)** use certbot to generate SSL for my-future-domain.com and www.my-future-domain.com
    `sudo certbot --nginx -d my-future-domain.com -d www.my-future-domain.com`

**3)** Select `2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access.` at certbot prompt

**4)** Add new `server_name` block for new domain name and mimic the current server block

*Current Block:*

```
#This server block will redirect http:// to https://www.my-current-domain.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-current-domain.com www.my-current-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.my-current-domain.com$request_uri;
}

#This server block will redirect https://my-current-domain.com to https://www.my-current-domain.com (expecting that you have a certificate for my-current-domain.com as well as www.my-current-domain.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-www.my-current-domain.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name my-current-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

*New Website Block:*

```
#This server block will redirect http:// to https://www.my-future-domain.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-future-domain.com www.my-future-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.my-future-domain.com$request_uri;
}

#This server block will redirect https://my-future-domain.com to https://www.my-future-domain.com (expecting that you have a certificate for my-future-domain.com as well as www.my-future-domain.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-www.my-future-domain.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name my-future-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

**5)** Redirect traffic from my-current-domain.com and www.my-current-domain.com to www.my-future-domain.com. Do I update "Current Block" from step 4?

**6)** Remove A and CNAME record for my-current-domain.com

Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, particularly around current block / new block. Please edit your question so it's clear what block is on which server now, and what your future state is for each server. Your domain names are also confusing - suggest you use "current.example.com" for the current domain and "future.example.com" for the future domain.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, but the two domain names are different, which is why I used such distinct domains. It isn't a new subdomain

Comment: [By convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) all URLs given as examples should be "example.com", and given you have two domains in your question I suggested using subdomains. It makes no technical difference what the domain name is or whether it's a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS looks proper. To simplify the DNS requests, you could make my-current-domain.com also set up as a CNAME to www.my-future-domain.com, not just www.my-current-domain.com. You wouldn't need to remove the DNS until the old domain expires; it is harmless to leave it in place. (It would also benefit anything that is still referencing the old domain by having it in place. The redirects should handle the rest.)

I would configure your server blocks as follows.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name my-future-domain.com www.my-future-domain.com my-current-domain.com www.my-current-domain.com;
        return 301 https://www.my-future-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.my-future-domain.com;
        …
```

You can clean up the code by combining the two server blocks.

If you pursue your current plan, if someone requested http://my-current-domain.com, they would be redirected to https://www.my-current-domain.com and then redirected again to https://www.my-future-domain.com. You can save on a redirect by having this all performed in the initial server block.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: " you could make my-current-domain.com also set up as a CNAME to www.my-future-domain.com" no, this is wrong, you can not put a CNAME at apex because it can not coexist with other records like the mandatory SOA and NS. BTW, use RFC2606 and RFC5737 for obfuscations needs

Comment: Would it be better to say that some DNS managers allow a CNAME for the main domain, but every domain would ultimately need an A record?